# Cordova Plugin - install last available version for specific platform

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios, cordova-android

the problem is the following one.

We need to install a different version of a plugin for platforms used in the project. More specifically we need to install version v2.1.2 for our cordova-android 6.4.0 platform and finally the v2.2.3 for cordova-ios 4.5.4.

**Question**

Avoiding to use external script just to assign right version at runtime based onto the current platform in preparing, cordova exposes some way to select the last supported version for a plugin ( making a check onto the current version in preparing/compiling ) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [plugman plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman/) which allows you to install specific plugins and versions to individual platforms.

```
plugman install --platform ios --plugin <name|url|path> --variable Version=4.5.4
plugman install --platform android --plugin <name|url|path> --variable Version=2.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks @brianfit for answer. Finally we decide in order to stay onto same build process line, to declare custom version inside a properties file and templatize the config.xml by ANT.